# Ошибка подключения WebSocket на хостинге

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, websocket

Я делаю первый проект на WebSocket, это простой чат, код сервера и клиента приведен ниже. При тестах на локальном сервере все работает хорошо, но если попробовать запустить на хостинге, то постоянно возникает ошибка:WebSocket connection to 'wss://https://testd.na4u.ru/:8000' failed:
(anonymous) @ (index):17.
На место адреса я пробовал вставлять адрес сайта, ip адрес, с разными портами(80, 443) и ws/wss. Однако единственное, что меняется - это то что в случае ниже ошибка вылетает не сразу, а через какое-то время. Файл index.html и server.js лежат в корне. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    <form id="messageForm">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>

    <div id="chat"></div>
    <script type="module">
        const chatEl = document.getElementById("chat");
        const ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000");
        ws.onmessage = (message) => {
            const messages = JSON.parse(message.data);
            messages.forEach((val) => {
                const messageEl = document.createElement('div');
                messageEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${val.name}: ${val.message}`));
                chat.appendChild(messageEl);
            })
        }
        const send = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            const message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                name, message
            }))
            return false;
        }
        const formEl = document.getElementById("messageForm");
        formEl.addEventListener("submit", send);

    </script>
```

Сервер:

```
import ws from "ws";
const {Server} = ws;
import {v4 as uuid} from "uuid";
import {writeFile, readFileSync, existsSync} from "fs";
const clients = {};
const log = existsSync('log') && readFileSync('log', 'utf-8');
const messages = log ? JSON.parse(log) : [];

const wss = new Server({port: 8000});
wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    const id = uuid();
    clients[id] = ws;

    console.log(`New client ${id}`);
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(messages));

    ws.on('message', (rawMessage) => {
        const {name, message} = JSON.parse(rawMessage);
        messages.push({name, message});
        for (const id in clients) {
            clients[id].send(JSON.stringify([{name, message}]))
        }
    })

    ws.on('close', () => {
        delete clients[id];
        console.log(`Client is closed ${id}`)
    })
})

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    wss.close();
    writeFile('log', JSON.stringify(messages), err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        process.exit();
    })
})
```

Comment: проблема в том, что у вас хостинг не настроен. Скорее всего, вам понадобиться сервер.

Comment: @Gelloiss А можно чуть подробнее, в общих чертах. А то я только начинаю заниматься серверной частью, немного тону в информации

Comment: Ну начать стоит с того, что у тебя локально как бы сервер. Ты там настроил все как надо, все как хочешь. Хостинг это одтн сервер настроеннгый на много проектов разных, рядом с твоим лежит еще штук 10 например. И хрен знает как он настроен. Какие порты (вот ты по 8000, например, пытался) открыты и доступны. Какие протоколы он принимает и как с ними работает (WebSocket это не http), да и в логе путь странный какой-то wss://https://testd.na4u.ru/:8000

Comment: Можете показать конфигурацию nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря @Gelloiss был найден ответ - проблема действительно состояла в настройке сервера. Для тех, кто столкнется с такой же проблемой "WebSocket connection to 'wss:...' failed", есть отличная статья [https://www.netangels.ru/support/cloud-hosting/websockets/][1]. Общие советы:

1. Еще раз проверьте код на локальном сервере на предмет ошибок;
2. Проверить порты. Особенность размещения node.js приложений на хостинге заключается в том, что приложению нужно прикрепиться не на порт 80 или 8080, а на определенные IP и порт;
3. Проверить ссылку на сервер. Необходимо указать, чтобы посетители сайта обращались к сайту, где включена поддержка вебсокетов;
4. Проверить сервер на поддержку веб - сокетов;
5. Проверить, какой файл для загрузки указан на серверной части. В панели управления сервера укажите файл server.js (как пример) в качестве файла для запуска приложения.